# PHP login condition error

Tags: php, mysql

i'm trying to make a simple login page in php, the code always echo "Sorry, your credentials are not valid, Please try again."...!! Please Help! :D

```
    <?php 
error_reporting(0);

$user ='root';
$host = 'localhost';
$db = 'christcode';
$db_pass = '';

$con=mysqli_connect("$host","$user","$db_pass","$db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }else{

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];


echo $username;
echo $password;
// Insert data into mysql 
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$username."' and password='".$password."' limit 1";
$result = mysqli_query($sql);
echo $result;




if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)
    echo"You are a validated user.";
else
    echo"Sorry, your credentials are not valid, Please try again.";
}
```

Comment: Beware, the "your code is subject to SQL injections" are coming !

Comment: Beside my useless comment, what is your question? is your code working?

Comment: You are mixing both `mysqli_` and `mysql_` API's

Comment: Are you storing your passwords in the database, in plaintext?

Comment: your code is subject to SQL injections

Answer (score 7):

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)
```

should be

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1)
```

you can't mix and match mysql_ and mysqli_ functions.

Comment: then it could be due to your query not returning anything. Did you check that ?

Comment: i knw!! this is not for main stream development..!! this is college project.!! so have to focus more on utility thn security..!! later i will secure it!

Comment: it has nothing to do with security. Is your basic query working and giving you the correct results? Can you echo the query and run it directly in MySQL ?

Comment: yaa!! i checked..!! it's not returning anything..!! i echoed $result and i guess it's empty.

Comment: yes!! SIR..!! I checked in mysql console and its working fine!!

Comment: echo $sql and not $result. The output of echo $sql, run it in your MySQL software like MySQL workbench or PHPMyAdmin and see if the query is correct.

Comment: yes!! IT'S correct and i did tht before posting the question here..! 
this is value of query "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='raman' and password='password' limit 1"

Comment: ok...what happens when you do this: $result = mysqli_query($sql); var_dump($result); exit;

Comment: it prints NULL and exits.

Comment: which means your query is not getting executed correctly. That could be because of the query syntax being incorrect (which doesn't seem to be the case here) or the query not returning anything. The control won't even go to that part of the code that checks for num rows returned.

Comment: so sir, how should i resolve this error??
i tell u the basic purpose of the programme...!! i just want to check if a user exists in the database.